# move to another branch and 'saving' current changes

Tags: git, github

Here's the scenario : I'm working on branch A but then something urgent need to be fix, how can I create a new branch (says it's branch B) without bringing over current changes?

I don't want to checkout all the files in branch A because I want to be able continue if the work in branch B is done.

I don't want to push branch A because it's unfinished.

Comment: just create a branch B off of master.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't want to checkout all the files in branch A because I want to be able continue if the work in branch B is done.

Comment: in git you do check out all of the files at once - but you can easily switch between branches.

Comment: @DanielA.White `checkout -- .` Can I restore them later?

Comment: yep you can commit and switch between branches. you can even use the stash feature.

Answer (score 9):

Option 1: You can stash your changes

If you have changes in Branch A:
while in branch A, do

```
git stash save "hint_to_what_stash_contains"
```

To retrieve the changes,

```
git stash apply
```

If you have multiple stashes, you can list them and choose which stash to apply.

```
git stash list
git stash apply stash@\{<STASH_NUMBER>\}
```

Option 2: Commit your changes.

First, commit all your changes in branchA but not push it to origin, then create your branch b to do your work.
Once branchB is done, you can checkout branch A to resume the work.

To resume work in branchA

```
git checkout brancha
edit files
git add <file(s)>
git commit --amend # You can also change the commit message if you want.
```

Option 3: Which i don't recommend, is the patch thing.. I have seen some people use it. Do a git diff and save it in a file Eg "branch_a_changes.patch" and when you want to resume your work just do
git apply branch_a_changes.patch

Answer (score 4):

You can commit your changes in `A`. Then Checkout `B`. When `B` is done, back to `A` and continue.

Or, If you don't want to commit the changes in 'A', [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) (save other place) the changes. And Checkout to `B` and when you back to `A` just take (`stash pop`) the changes from `stash`.

> `Stashing` takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time

- Options-1: Commit

  ```
  $ git checkout A                      # chekcout A
  $ git commit -am 'tmp commit'         # add & commit

  $ git checkout B                      # checkout B
  // fix your urgent changes here

  $ git checkout A
  // continue A
  ```
- Options-2: Stash

  ```
  $ git checkout A    
  $ git add .
  $ git stash                           # save unfinished changes

  $ git checkout B                      # checkout B
  // fix your urgent changes here

  $ git checkout A                      # checkout A
  $ git stash apply                     # retrieve the changes from stash

  // you can clear the stash
  $ git stash drop                      # remove the changes from stash
  ```

Comment: commit for single branch ; while stash make changes available across multiple branches?

Comment: @Jamie Anderson Yes, In any branch you can get back the changes by just `git stash apply` command.

Answer (score 3):

From `git worktree --help` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

> You are in the middle of a refactoring session and your boss comes in
>   and demands that you fix something immediately. You
>          might typically use git-stash(1) to store your changes away temporarily, however, your working tree is in such a state of
>          disarray (with new, moved, and removed files, and other bits and pieces strewn around) that you don't want to risk
>          disturbing any of it. Instead, you create a temporary linked working tree to make the emergency fix, remove it when done,
>          and then resume your earlier refactoring session.
>
> ```
>        $ git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master
>        $ pushd ../temp
>        # ... hack hack hack ...
>        $ git commit -a -m 'emergency fix for boss'
>        $ popd
>        $ rm -rf ../temp
>        $ git worktree prune
> ```

Comment: `git worktree add` was new in Git 2.5, with some important fixes in 2.6 and minor ones since then.  I have started using it in 2.9 and later and recommend it now.